# Scrapy Closed early without error message

Tags: python, django, pagination, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a simple pagination spider like so

```
import scrapy    

class AuthorSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'author'

start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']
pending_authors = {}

def parse(self, response):

    # process pagination links
    next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').extract_first()
    next_page_request = None
    if next_page is not None:
        next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
        # Create the Request object, but does not yield it now
        next_page_request = scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)

    # Requests scrapping of authors, and pass reference to the Request for next page
    for href in response.css('.author+a::attr(href)').extract():
        self.pending_authors[href] = False  # Marks this author as 'not processed'
        yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(href), callback=self.parse_author,
                             meta={'next_page_request': next_page_request}, dont_filter=True)


def parse_author(self, response):
    def extract_with_css(query):
        return response.css(query).extract_first().strip()

    item = {
        'name': extract_with_css('h3.author-title::text'),
        'birthdate': extract_with_css('.author-born-date::text'),
        'bio': extract_with_css('.author-description::text'),
    }

    # marks this author as 'processed'
    self.pending_authors[response.url] = True

    # checks if finished processing of all authors
    if len([value for key, value in self.pending_authors.iteritems() if value == False]) == 0:
        yield item
        next_page_request = response.meta['next_page_request']

        # Requests next page, after finishing all authors
        self.pending_authors = {}
        yield next_page_request
    else:
        yield item
```

I store all of my items into a Django DB. I also have a middleware that will raise an IgnoreRequest if the requestURL is in the DB.

Randomly, the crawler will stop with a regular finish message. It also completely stops if it sees a page where all of the authors are already crawled and not go to the next page. This is a problem if Scrapy finishes early but there are still pages remaining, as starting from page 0 will always instantly shut down the crawler. I want it to keep paginating past these pages, but still ignore pre-crawled authors. Also, I want to figure out why Scrapy is randomly finishing early (despite seeing new data).

Here is the error message:

```
2017-01-18 21:03:45 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET website.com> (referer: None)
<QuerySet [<Quotes object>]>
<QuerySet [<Quotes object>]>
<QuerySet [<Quotes object>]>
<QuerySet [<Quotes object>]>
<QuerySet [<Quotes object>]>
<QuerySet [<Quotes object>]>
<QuerySet [<Quotes object>]>
<QuerySet [<Quotes object>]>
<QuerySet [<Quotes object>]>
<QuerySet [<Quotes object>]>
<QuerySet [<Quotes object>]>
<QuerySet [<Quotes object>]>
<QuerySet [<Quotes object>]>
<QuerySet [<Quotes object>]>
<QuerySet [<Quotes object>]>
<QuerySet [<Quotes object>]>
<QuerySet [<Quotes object>]>
<QuerySet [<Quotes object>]>
<QuerySet [<Quotes object>]>
<QuerySet [<Quotes object>]>
2017-01-18 21:03:46 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-01-18 21:03:46 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 24,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/scrapy.exceptions.IgnoreRequest': 24,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 504,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 24256,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 19, 5, 3, 46, 77921),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 25,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 25,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 25,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 25,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 19, 5, 3, 44, 73413)}
2017-01-18 21:03:46 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```